# Object Reference Not Set DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm still learning MVC and am confused. I am converting a windows application for CRUD with a database to an MVC website. I got an entire ViewModel's CRUD working that uses dropdownlist's already and the code is identical but throwing object reference not set errors with it in another page.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var shiftsEmployees = new ShiftsEmployeesViewModel();

    var oEmployees = new CEmployees();
    oEmployees.GetActiveEmployees();

    shiftsEmployees.Employees = oEmployees;

    return View(shiftsEmployees);
}

// POST: Shifts/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ShiftsEmployeesViewModel shiftsEmployees)
{
    try
    {
        shiftsEmployees.InsertShift();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View

```
@model StatTracker.ASPMVC.ViewModels.ShiftsEmployeesViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Add Shift";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal text-center">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shift.Date, new {@class = "control-label"})&nbsp;
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Shift.Date, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Pick a date"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Shift.Date, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.FullName, new {@class = "control-label"})&nbsp;
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee.Id, new SelectList(Model.Employees.Employees, "Id", "FullName", Model.Employee), null, null)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.Id, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Shift.Hours, new {@class = "control-label"})&nbsp;
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Shift.Hours, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Hours worked"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Shift.Hours, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Shift" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<div class="text-center col-md-12">
      @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace StatTracker.ASPMVC.ViewModels
{
    public class ShiftsEmployeesViewModel
    {
        public CShift Shift { get; set; }
        public CEmployee Employee { get; set; }
        public CEmployees Employees { get; set; }

        public void InsertShift()
        {
            CShift.InsertShift(hours: Shift.Hours, employeeid: Employee.Id, date: Shift.Date);
        }

        public void UpdateShift()
        {
            CShift.UpdateShift(hours: Shift.Hours, employeeid: Employee.Id, date: Shift.Date, shiftid: Shift.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

working code with same idea
controller

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var oSalesEmployeeService = new SalesEmployeeServiceViewModel();

        var oServices = new CServices();
        oServices.GetServices();

        var oEmployees = new CEmployees();
        oEmployees.GetActiveEmployees();

        oSalesEmployeeService.Employees = oEmployees;
        oSalesEmployeeService.Services = oServices;

        return View(oSalesEmployeeService);
    }

    // POST: Sales/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SalesEmployeeServiceViewModel oSalesEmployeeService)
    {
        try
        {
            oSalesEmployeeService.InsertSale();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

viewmodel

```
using StatTracker.BL;

namespace StatTracker.ASPMVC.ViewModels
{
public class SalesEmployeeServiceViewModel
{
    public CSale Sale { get; set; }
    public CEmployees Employees { get; set; }
    public CServices Services { get; set; }
    public CEmployee Employee { get; set; }
    public CService Service { get; set; }

    public void InsertSale()
    {
        CSale.InsertSale(service: Service.Id, date: Sale.Date, employee: Employee.Id);
    }

    public void UpdateSale()
    {
        CSale.UpdateSale(service: Service.Id, date: Sale.Date, employee: Employee.Id, salesid: Sale.Id);
    }
  }
}
```

view

```
@model StatTracker.ASPMVC.ViewModels.SalesEmployeeServiceViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add Sale";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal text-center">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sale.Date, new {@class = "control-label"})&nbsp;
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sale.Date, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Pick a date"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sale.Date, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.FullName, new {@class = "control-label"})&nbsp;
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee.Id, new SelectList(Model.Employees.Employees, "Id", "FullName", Model.Employee), null, null)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.Id, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Service.Description, new {@class = "control-label"})&nbsp;
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Service.Id, new SelectList(Model.Services.Services, "Id", "Description", Model.Service), null, null)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service.Id, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Sale" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div class="text-center col-md-12">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: This is likely to be closed very quickly as a duplicate to the master question regarding `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` unless you can demonstrate how the answers there aren't useful to your situation;  More specifically, you haven't even indicated here which variables are null or which line of code is throwing the error.

Comment: It happens on the DropDownListFor... like stated in the title. That reference doesn't help me...as I show you that I am instantiating the object. I have looked over this for hours and need new eyes.

Comment: The link does help you. You need to learn to debug your code, which would tell you that the value of `Model.Employees.Employees` is null when you return the view. But you have other issues as well s I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not indicated exactly where the error is being thrown but there will be numerous reasons

Firstly, a view model is not just a holder for a series of data models. It should contain only those properties which you need to display/edit in the view. Currently if any properties of `CShift` or `CEmployee` have validation attributes (other that the `Date` and `Hours` properties), your model will be invalid.

Secondly, when you return the view, you need to return the model to the view and also assign the value of `Employees` which currently will be null (hence the exception when you access `Model.Employees.Employees` in the `DropDownList()` method).

Based on the view you have shown, your view model should be just (add validation attributes as required)

```
public class ShiftsEmployeesViewModel
{
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  public int Employee { get; set; }
  public float Hours { get; set; }
  public SelectList EmployeeList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ShiftsEmployeesViewModel model = new ShiftsEmployeesViewModel();
  model.Employee = ? // set default selection
  ConfigureCreateModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ShiftsEmployeesViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureCreateModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  .... // map the view model properties to a new instance of the data model, save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureCreateModel(ShiftsEmployeesViewModel model)
{
  var oEmployees = (new CEmployees()).GetActiveEmployees();
  model.EmployeeList = new SelectList(oEmployees, "Id", "FullName");
}
```

View

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Employee)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Employee, Model.EmployeeList, "-please select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Employee)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Hours)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Hours)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Shift.Hours)
```

Side note: Your current usage of `SelectList(Model.Employees.Employees, "Id", "FullName", Model.Employee)` where you use the 4th parameter is pointless. Your binding to a property, so attempting to set the value of the `Selected` is ignored (the selected option is based on the value of the property your binding to)

Comment: I appreciate the lessons on MVC design, I know that I was getting frustrated and my responses were less than warranting of this level of help. I am sorry I can't +1 your answer, but it solved my problem with the addition of converting CEmployee to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because model.Employee has not been initialized and therefore, model.Employee.Id will throw a null reference exception. After that You still need to initialize the shift object as it will also throw a null reference exception when model.Shift.Hours is accessed. Please see my suggestions below

You will have to initialize the remaining properties

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var oEmployees = new CEmployees();
    oEmployees.GetActiveEmployees();

    var shiftsEmployees = new ShiftsEmployeesViewModel
    {
        Employee = new CEmployee(),
        Shift = new CShift(),
        Employees = oEmployees;
    };

    return View(shiftsEmployees);
}
```

Another option is to just always initialize them in the constructor of the view model (you just have to make sure that somewhere GetActiveEmployees is getting called)

```
public class ShiftsEmployeesViewModel
{
    public ShiftsEmployeesViewModel()
    {
        this.oEmployees = new CEmployees();
        this.Employee = new CEmployee();
        this.Shift = new CShift();
    }
 }
```

Also change the implementation in your view for the dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee.Id, 
                      new SelectList(Model.Employees.Employees ?? new List<CEmployee>(), 
                                     "Id", 
                                     "FullName"))
```

Comment: implemented both solutions and still getting an exception on the same line :S @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee.Id, new SelectList(Model.Employees.Employees, "Id", "FullName", Model.Employee), null, null)

Comment: My assumption is that GetActiveEmployees is not initializing Employees. Can you try this? 
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee.Id,  new SelectList(Model.Employees.Employees ?? new List<CEmployee>(), "Id", "FullName"))

Comment: same thing... this is so defeating